# unable to read file from standard input in asyncio

Tags: input, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I have written a code that works on asyncio. In that code I had to read a file from standard input using `./check.py < file.txt`
I am able to give input from terminal. normally it works fine.
But it doesn't work for reading data from file from standard input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import asyncio
from aioconsole import ainput

async def read_input():
    while True:
        inp = await ainput()
        print('got ' + inp)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(read_input())
```

normally it works like

```
$ ./check.py 
4
got 4
5
got 5
```

But while reading from file directly I face this log:

```
$ ./check.py < test/test_case 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./check.py", line 12, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(read_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "./check.py", line 8, in read_input
    inp = await ainput()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aioconsole/stream.py", line 156, in ainput
    reader, writer = yield from get_standard_streams(loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aioconsole/stream.py", line 144, in get_standard_streams
    cache[key] = yield from connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aioconsole/stream.py", line 132, in create_standard_streams
    reader, writer = yield from future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aioconsole/stream.py", line 114, in open_pipe_connection
    yield from loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: protocol, pipe_in)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1099, in connect_read_pipe
    transport = self._make_read_pipe_transport(pipe, protocol, waiter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 185, in _make_read_pipe_transport
    return _UnixReadPipeTransport(self, pipe, protocol, waiter, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 353, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Pipe transport is for pipes/sockets only.")
ValueError: Pipe transport is for pipes/sockets only.
```

Unable to get why is it behaving differently ? 
I want to read a file like `./check.py < file.txt` using coroutines.

Comment: This looks very much like a bug :) Could you please report it on the [aioconsole issue tracker](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole/issues)?

Comment: sure i will post that and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole/issues/28) that has been fixed in [aioconsole v0.1.9](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole/releases/tag/v0.1.9).

Simply run the following command to get the latest version:

```
$ pip3 install -U aioconsole
```

Comment: right now i am unable to get the latest version. I am using python3.6 and using pip3.6. I am getting "Requirement already up-to-date: aioconsole in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.1.8)"

Comment: done. the command runs successfully :) it took some time for changes to take effect :)